# Change lim from -k to k

Tags: limits, derivatives

\begin{align*}
f\,''(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f\,'(x)-f\,'(x-h)}h\\
&=\lim_{-k\to0}\frac{f\,'(x)-f\,'(x-(-k))}{-k}\\
&=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f\,'(x-(-k))-f(x)}k\\
&=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f\,'(x+k)-f(x)}k\;,
\end{align*}

Can someone explain why he can changed from -k to k?

Comment: multiply both sides by $-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing $k$ by $-k$ is legitimate since this change results in switching left-hand limits with right-hand limits, that is, $-k\to 0^+$ is equivalent to $k\to 0^-$. We are interested in a two-sided limit, so the result doesn't change.